# Custom layout not working : m2

Tags: magento2, custom, custompage

**Jimit\Categorytree\registration.php**

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Jimit_Categorytree',
        __DIR__
    );
```

**Jimit\Categorytree\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jimit_Categorytree" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

**Jimit\Categorytree\etc\frontend\routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="categorytree" frontName="categorytree">
            <module name="Jimit_Categorytree" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Jimit\Categorytree\Controller\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Jimit\Categorytree\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action {

    private $pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
        return $page;
    }
}
```

**Jimit\Categorytree\Block\Categorytree.php**

```
<?php

namespace Jimit\Categorytree\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Categorytree extends Template
{
    public function getText() {
        return "Category";
    }
}
```

**Jimit\Categorytree\view\frontend\layout\categorytree_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Jimit\Categorytree\Block\Categorytree" name="categorytree" template="Jimit_Categorytree::categorytree.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Jimit\Categorytree\view\frontend\templates\categorytree.phtml**

```
JIMIT Test
```

**URL:** 
https://localhost/Magento-CE-2_3_3/categorytree/index/index

When I run URL in browser white blank screen showing, not getting any error while commands and also not in logs.

Can anyone help me to find an issue?

**Note:** I have debugged, both methods from the controller are calling.

Thanks

Comment: Hit this: https://localhost/Magento-CE-2_3_3/categorytree/index/index

Comment: Your frontend route name is 'categorytree'  not categorynewtree.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you hit this:  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Check if your module enable and disable after hitting above command.

Well, It's Working Now.

[image]

Comment: I have already run all commands but it's  not working for me

Comment: Do you need codebase?

Answer (score 0):

try this `step by step`

> **Jimit/Categorytree/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Jimit_Categorytree',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **Jimit/Categorytree/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jimit_Categorytree" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> **Jimit/Categorytree/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="categorytree" id="categorytree">
            <module name="Jimit_Categorytree"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> **Jimit/Categorytree/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Jimit\Categorytree\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> **Jimit/Categorytree/Block/Categorytree.php**

```
<?php
namespace Jimit\Categorytree\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Categorytree extends Template
{

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getText() {

        return "Category";
    }
}
```

> **Jimit/Categorytree/view/frontend/layout/categorytree_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <update handle="customer_account"/>
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Jimit\Categorytree\Block\Categorytree" name="categorytree" template="Jimit_Categorytree::categorytree.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

> **Jimit/Categorytree/view/frontend/templates/categorytree.phtml**

```
 <?php
/**
 * @var Jimit\Categorytree\Block\Categorytree $block;
 */
 ?>
<h4><?= $block->getText(); ?></h4>
```

> **Run CLI commands**

```
php bin/magento module:enable Jimit_Categorytree
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento ca:cl
php bin/magento ca:fl
Set permission
```

**URL: https://localhost/Magento-CE-2_3_3/categorytree/index/index**

I hope this will help you..!